# Remove Duplicate Fields Used for document_id Before Elasticsearch in Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I wrote my own filter for Logstash and I'm trying to calculate my own `document_id` something like this:

```
  docIdClean = "%d %s %s %s" % [ event["@timestamp"].to_f * 1000, event["type"], event["message"] ]    
  event["docId"] = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(docIdClean)
```

And the Logstash configuration looks like this:

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    ...
    index => "analysis-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    document_id => "%{docId}"
    template_name => "logstash_per_index"
  }
}
```

The more or less minor downside is that all documents in Elasticsearch contain `_id` and `docId` holding the same value. Since `docId` is completely pointless as nobody searches for an MD5-hash I want to remove it, but I don't know how.

The `docId` has to exist when the event hits the output, otherwise the output can't refer to it. Therefore, I can't remove it beforehand. Since I can't remove it afterwards, the `docId` sits there occupying space.

I tried to set the event field `_id`, but that only causes an exception in Elasticsearch that the id of the document is different.

Maybe for explanation here one document:

```
  {
    "_index": "analysis-2014.09.16",
    "_type": "access",
    "_id": "022d9055423cdd0756b6cfa06886f866",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "@timestamp": "2014-09-16T19:36:31.000+02:00",
      "type": "access",
      "tags": [
        "personalized"
      ],
      "importDate": "2014/09/17",
      "docId": "022d9055423cdd0756b6cfa06886f866"
    }
  }
```

EDIT:
*This is about Logstash 1.3*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing you can do about this in Logstash 1.4.

In Logstash 1.5, you can use [@metadata fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/configuration.html#metadata), which are not passed to Elasticsearch.